# Problem with function parametrs i cant refer to this function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, object, javascript-objects

```
let confirmed = {};
let deaths = {};
let recovered = {};
const objectWithParams = (param) =>
  getCountryInfo.map((item) => {
    let year, month, day;
    const formatDate = ([year, month, day] = item.date
      .split("-")
      .map((element) => parseInt(element)));
    for (var i = 0; i < getCountryInfo.length; i++) {
      param = { x: new Date(formatDate), y: item.param };
    }
    return param;
  });

confirmed = objectWithParams(`confirmed`);
console.log(confirmed);
```

how i can refer to the function parametr during it is mapping

this code in console.log show me that "y" is undefined, how i can do that it will be good?

Comment: could you provide the `getCountryInfo` array? How would you like to "refer" to the function parameter?

Comment: What is `getCountryInfo` variable here?

Comment: its a array-object who have for example

0: {date: "2020-1-22", confirmed: 0, deaths: 0, recovered: 0}

Comment: I think it should be `item[param]` instead of `item.param` and `param = ..` doesn't make sense, you're redefining a variable inside a loop.

Comment: item[param] doesnt work, undefined all the time

Comment: param of object

Comment: There is no `param` property in the object you have shared `{date: "2020-1-22", confirmed: 0, deaths: 0, recovered: 0}`

Comment: @RetupK item[param] doesnt work because you're overriding param variable.

do _param = { x: new Date(formatDate), y: item.param }; and return _param;

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to iterate again. You are already iterating in `map`.

**Sample:**

```js
let confirmed = {};
let deaths = {};
let recovered = {};
const objectWithParams = (param) =>
  param.map(({ date, ...rest }) => {
    const formatDate = date.split("-").map((element) => parseInt(element));
    return { x: new Date(formatDate), ...rest };
  });

confirmed = objectWithParams([
  {
    date: "03-04-2020",
    death: 10,
    active: 12,
    recovered: 10,
  },
  {
    date: "03-01-2020",
    death: 10,
    active: 12,
    recovered: 10,
  },
  {
    date: "03-02-2020",
    death: 10,
    active: 12,
    recovered: 10,
  },
  {
    date: "03-04-2020",
    death: 10,
    active: 12,
    recovered: 10,
  },
]);
console.log(confirmed);
```

Mapper Function:

```js
let confirmed = {};
let deaths = {};
let recovered = {};
class Mapper {
  constructor(array, key) {
    this.map = array.reduce((map, item) => {
      const val = item[key];
      if (!map[val]) {
        map[val] = [];
      }
      map[val].push(item);
      return map;
    }, {});
  }

  find(key) {
    return this.map[key] && this.map[key][Mapper.FIRST_INDEX]; //return blank array
  }

  findAll(key, returnUndefined) {
    //return blank array
    return this.map[key] ? this.map[key] : returnUndefined ? undefined : [];
  }
}

Mapper.FIRST_INDEX = 0;
const data = [
  {
    date: "03-04-2020",
    death: 10,
    confirmed: 12,
    recovered: 12,
  },
  {
    date: "03-01-2020",
    death: 10,
    confirmed: 12,
    recovered: 10,
  },
  {
    date: "03-02-2020",
    death: 10,
    confirmed: 12,
    recovered: 23,
  },
  {
    date: "03-04-2020",
    death: 10,
    confirmed: 21,
    recovered: 10,
  },
]

var userMapper = new Mapper(data, "confirmed"); // create a map on names
console.log(JSON.stringify(userMapper.map, null, 4)); //will return only user with name 'Schmidt'
userMapper = new Mapper(data, "recovered"); // create a map on names
console.log(JSON.stringify(userMapper.map, null, 4)); //will return only user with name 'Schmidt'
```

Comment: I want to have date, death, active, recovered in different objects for example when i use function objectWithParams("confirmed") 

 this create me object with value of confirmed

Comment: you mean match, all confirmed and return ??

Comment: checkout my other solution, using this mapper util u can map on any key.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you were looking for (xdeepakv almost had it the first time I think)

```js
const data = [
  {
    date: "03-04-2020",
    death: 10,
    active: 12,
    recovered: 10,
  },
  {
    date: "03-01-2020",
    death: 10,
    active: 12,
    recovered: 10,
  },
  {
    date: "03-02-2020",
    death: 10,
    active: 12,
    recovered: 10,
  },
  {
    date: "03-04-2020",
    death: 10,
    active: 12,
    recovered: 10,
  },
]

const objectWithParams = (param) =>
  data.map(({ date, [param]:y }) => {
    const formatDate = date.split("-").map((element) => parseInt(element));
    return { x: new Date(formatDate), y };
  });

confirmed = objectWithParams('death');
console.log(confirmed);
```